# Codeigniter search for a value inside result array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Which function can I use to check if a value exists in a result array? 
I tried it the  following way but it failed.

```
$query = $this->db->query($query);
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (in_array('Receive', $result)) {
            echo 'this array contains Receive';
        }
```

Comment: dump your db result ($result) and look, if the value exists.

Comment: asking same question again?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

it will show the last query you executed. Just put it at the end of your function.

**EDIT:**

Sorry I thought you were asking about the query, my bad. However, if you want to know if your query returned a value in the form of an array, you can use:

```
$result = $query->result_array();
print_r($result);
```